# is there a way to set up the output sequeue of a printf function?

Tags: c++, lua

for example

```
printf("%d, %d", num1, num2) 
string.format("%d, %d", num1, num2)
```

I want to output the num2 first
without modify the param order in params table
just modify the format string to reach my point

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are asking about C++ or lua

Answer (score 3):

No such thing in C or C++ `printf`.

POSIX specifies that `printf` and friends can use positional arguments, as an extension for C:

```
printf("%2$d, %1$d", 33, 42); // prints 42, 33
```

Kind people at Microsoft support this, but for our greater convenience they have named the functions differently, e.g. `_printf_p`.

Lua `format` used to support this until 4.0, but in version 5 somebody, deity of choice bless their soul, decided to declare this "obsolete" and removed this feature. I don't know what, if any, Lua facility replaces it.

Comment: My sarcasm sense is tingling.

Comment: GNU libC supports the same notation... see [*12.12.2 Output Conversion Syntax*](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Output-Conversion-Syntax), and specifically *param-no*.

Comment: @TonyD GNU libC largely implements POSIX, so it does support this kinda naturally.

Comment: With the "POSIX extension / Microsoft support this" form, your answer could easily be misunderstand to mean that Microsoft is unusual in supporting this feature, so I was just making it explicit that GNU libC provides it....

Answer (score 0):

yeah, I got my way here:
print("test rsult"..string.gsub("hello param1 world from Lua param2", "param%d", {param1=25, param2="Jesus"}))